# How do you get new items or blocks on older versions of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to put new blocks on earlier versions of Minecraft

Comment: update or mod, but i doubt that there are mods for things that are in the base game

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible without mods.

Comment: ....or updating